# Can i use 1500 mA power adaptor for sata to usb convertor cable

Tags: hard-drive, sata, adapter

I have a SATA to usb convertor cable which only requires only 12V 1 Ampere of current but I have got 1500mA power adaptor with 12V is it safe to provide 1.5A power source to the 3.5inch hdd through SATA to usb cable..

Comment: If it wants 1 Ampere, but you can only provide 1.5 milliAmpere, then it will not be enough.

Comment: possible answer: https://superuser.com/a/285946/912095

Comment: You most certainly do not have a 1.5 mA power adapter. Please update your question with the actual rating, including the voltage rating on both SATA adapter and power supply.

Comment: mA is 1/1,000 A. Read the rating.

Comment: 1500mA = 1.5 amps.  your subsequent syntax of `1.5mA` is a typo

Comment: yes it was typical mistake sorry for that

Comment: with anything u need a power supply having a rating `equal or greater ` than the draw current of the device (or load).  And it's always better to have 10% or more above the device rating.  You *need* 1 amp but your power adapter is 1.5 amp, you are good!.  Only talking about 1 amp here, at 12v.   1.5 is ~60% greater than 1.0 but we're only talking about 1 amp @ 12v or 12 watts.

Comment: tnx buddy for the answer i needed

Answer (score 0):

When looking at power requirements for electrical goods, the following stands:

Voltage is critical: 
if the Voltage of the charger is higher than what is required, this will damage the device. 
if the Voltage of the charger is lower than the device, more than likely, the device will not power on and could damage the charger.

Current is less critical (as in that you are less likely to do any damage to any equipment).
The only rule you really need to follow with regards to the current is, the charger needs to provide at least (more than) the amps needed for the device.

Therefore, the charger you proposed would work safely and without issues, as long as there are no faults with the charger.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not to complicate things, but the converter cable does not require 1A.  The converter can be used with drives of different power requirements.  The attached drive needs whatever power it needs  The converter uses a small amount of additional current for itself.

   If you're seeing 1A somewhere on the converter, that's likely a maximum capacity of either the cable or the power supply that came with it.  That would be assumed to be adequate for any drive you would connect.  The actual power requirement will be a little higher than the requirement of whatever drive you're connecting to it.
2. How much current flows is determined by the effective resistance of the drive and converter, and the voltage you apply to it.  As long as the power supply can provide the voltage, that's the current that will flow.

   The current capacity of the power supply or converter just describes the maximum current you can draw before it is damaged.  If the new power supply can provide more current than what is needed, that's just a safety margin.  Recognize that for drives with a low power requirement, the original power supply also would have had more capacity than needed.